# Non-vanishing vector fields on the 2 Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Can you explicitly construct several non vanishing vector fields on the 2 Torus $S^1 \times S^1$? How can you build non zero vector fields in this particular case? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, on any manifold, given any two independent vector fields, you can take linear combinations of them to get lots of others.

So, take the vector field $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ pointing along the first circle, and the vector field $\frac{d}{d\phi}$ pointing along the second circle. Now form linear combinations $r \cdot \frac{d}{d\theta} + s \cdot \frac{d}{d\phi}$ to get infinitely many nowhere zero vector fields.

---

**Added:**  Illustrated examples:

[image] $\qquad$ [image]

Comment: To the OP:  to make it clear, $r$ can be a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$, as can $s$.  The only important condition is that $r$ and $s$ don't simultaneously vanish.

Comment: Do you think the constant vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ does not vanish? Here we take some coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$. These coordinates are the coordinates induced by $S^1$. Should I express this vector field in the other charts to conclude that does not vanish? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nonvanishing of the vector field is independent of coordinates. So, once you know that the vector field does not vanish in $\theta,\phi$ coordinates, it follows that it does not vanish in any other coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I forgot to ask. These charts are missing two circles, you don't have a global parametrization of these torus. You have to use several charts.

How do you manage this?

Comment: No charts are involved. $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$ are global vector fields. Any linear combination of them is a global vector field.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think about one of the two canonical circles in the torus and how you can foliate a the torus with it.

Comment: I am sorry, I don’t know anything about foliations. Could you elaborate a little bit your answer please?

Comment: You don't need to know anything about foliations formally. What I want you to notice is that if you take one circle wrapping around and you move it around the torus then the velocity vector of the those circles is a non vanishing vector field.

Comment: It may be more clear if you make a picture of a torus. Maybe it is good to have in mind that saying "foliate" just means that you are covering a manifold with copies of another manifold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: That is a very incorrect definition of a foliation, YTS.